# Camera image processing

Tags: java, image, image-processing

Basically I have a camera chip (Camera module: C3038, uses OmniVision’s CMOS image sensor OV6630) connected to a PC through a RS232 link.  I want to read image data in a Java program which is in this format (according to camera specification):

Data format - YCrCb 4:2:2, GRB 4:2:2, RGB Raw Data

Any hints on how to do it?

My implementation:

```
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.PortInUseException;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEvent;
import gnu.io.SerialPortEventListener;
import gnu.io.UnsupportedCommOperationException;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class SimpleRead1 implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {
static CommPortIdentifier portId;
static Enumeration portList;

InputStream inputStream;
SerialPort serialPort;
Thread readThread;
byte [] readBuffer;
static byte [] storeBuffer;

public SimpleRead1() {
    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("SimpleReadApp", 2000);
    }catch (PortInUseException e) {System.out.println(e);}

    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    }catch (IOException e) {System.out.println(e);}

    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {System.out.println(e);}

    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {System.out.println(e);}

    readThread = new Thread(this);
    readThread.start();
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e);}
}

@Override
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event){
    switch(event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
        readBuffer = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE];

        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {

                int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
                System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
            }
           } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(readBuffer);
        BufferedImage image = null;

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        //GUI for displaying image
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(imageIcon);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("image display");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);                       
        break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

    while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
        if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
             if (portId.getName().equals("COM7")) {
        //                if (portId.getName().equals("/dev/term/a")) {
                SimpleRead1 reader = new SimpleRead1();
           }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Camera module : C3038, uses OmniVision’s CMOS image sensor OV6630.

Comment: Thanks, edited that info. into the question to make it more prominent.  Don't know the answer, but interesting question.  +1

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Java does not support serial ports on its own - you need an external library for that. I would suggest taking a look at [the RXTX library](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), which seems to be somewhat of a defacto standard these days.

Video sensor chips usually have relatively simple communication interfaces on their own (i.e. without a bridge chip). Usually it boils down to setting the image parameters, initiating the actual image data transfer and then reading a number of bytes into a buffer. Sometimes an image data start or end signature may be involved, but that's about it.

It should not be *too* hard if you have all the documentation for you chip at hand - I have occasionally done something similar in C without *any* documentation...

**EDIT:**

Once you have read the image to a byte array, you might be able to use [the BufferedImage class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) to make it usable for Java. That said, I have not been able to determine if Java supports anything but ARGB variations - you may have to do the color-space conversion on your own (or via a third-party library, I suppose) if you want to use a non-RGB mode in your sensor.

Comment: thanks I know how to read from a COM port using RXTX library but the what I need is to process that data from the COM port into an image in Java

Comment: Code edited and uploaded..However, is there a way I could detect the end of image to stop the while loop which is while(inputStream.available () > 0)

Comment: @stud91: well, the obvious way would be to count the number of bytes. Raw images have a fixed byte size, depending on the resolution and the bytes/pixel. Beware of padding bits in formats with e.g. 12 bits/pixel. Some sensors also have delimiter byte sequences. You should check your sensor documentation for details on its supported output formats...

Comment: The documentation found here says that the resolution is 356x292 and the image output that i have programmed is to be 8-bit so the image size should be 356x292x8 = 831,616 bits = 103952 bytes.
(http://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/FinalProjects/s2011/kj83_twl46/docs/OV6330.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

The question is kind of broad so I don't know how much experience you have but for RS-232 you are going to need to use a SerialPort. [Here](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=11) is a simple example to get you started reading from a COM port.